# AWS lambda exits before callback hit

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am experiencing an issue with AWS Lambda with Node 8.10 existing early with the implicit `null` returned callback:

```
const request = require('request');

exports.handler = async (event, ctx, callback) => {
    console.log(`Fetching '${event.url}'...`);
    request(event.url, (err, body) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, body);
    });
}
```

This is a basic example of the problem I have in my own much larger lambda function. Essentially, when I make a call to a 3rd party resource, the Lambda finishes before the callback is reached.

I have read several documentation pages and SO posts that refer to:
`callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` but setting this to false does not change the behaviour.

I have managed to force it to wait for the response by wrapping the code in a promise then using `await` before calling `callback` but is this really necessary?

```
exports.handler = async (event, ctx, callback) => {
    
    const executeLambda = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(`Fetching '${event.url}'...`);
        request(event.url, (err, body) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(body);
        });
    });

    await executeLambda
        .then((res) => callback(null, res))
        .catch(callback);
}
```

Note: I am mocking this locally with `docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:nodejs8.10 index.handler '{"url": "https://www.google.com"}'`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I declared the handler with `async`. The following works:

```
const request = require('request');

exports.handler = (event, ctx, callback) => {
    console.log(`Fetching '${event.url}'...`);
    request(event.url, (err, body) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        return callback(null, body);
    });
}
```